# KafkaStream KTable dump

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

My question is regarding dumping a KTable whose values meet a certain criteria when a trigger message is received.

Here is an example of this problem:

KTable - CurrentAccountBalance

```
   John    +10,
   Joe     -1,
   Alice   -2,
   Jill    +5,
```

My requirement is to fetch all the records having negative balance on a incoming event: `FETCH_NEGATIVE_BALANCE_ENTRIES` which arrives
on a different command stream.

My thinking was this:
If we do a *leftJoin on CurrentAccountBalance KTable* with the command stream we can dump all entries of CurrentAccountBalance (which can be used for filter), but, that is not happening.

ValueJoiner of leftJoin only receives the command on right and null on left (rather than all
entries of CurrentAccountBalance). Am I missing something ?

thanks

Comment: Welcome. Please include the code that you have tried, even though it failed, and explain why/where it failed. I suggest that you re-read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and edit your question to suit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single input message in a KTable join, will produce one (or zero) output messages in Kafka Stream, because KTable joins are base on primary keys.

What you could do, is to create a custom `transformer` that received the commands and that is connected to the KTable state (if you specify the KTable store name, you can easily connect the state to the transformer). When a command is received, you can get a `state.all()` iterator and search for all entries that match your condition and emit them via `context.forward()` plus a sink that is downstream to the transformer.

Comment: One followup question on this:
If the app has multiple instances they would have multiple state-stores, is there a way to ensure that the command is sent to all instances of the application ? I am currently considering sending the FETCH command to all partitions, not sure how it would work when an app handles multiple partitions. So, was curious if there is a better way to send a message to all app instances. thanks

Comment: I guess, you would need to send the command to all partitions. I cannot think an any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have implemented to dump KTable entries meeting a certain criteria. Describing it here for anyone else looking for a similar solution in future.

1. Created a custom mapper (FlatMapper) to generate the messages meeting a condition. I have passed state-store as a constructor argument to this mapper.
2. Created a Event called 'FLUSH_NEGATIVE_BALANCES' and read it on a new KStream called a commandStream
3. When this new FLUSH command is received, I invoke the flatmapper created in step1 to generate the messages meeting the condition (negative balances in my case)
4. I write the output of flatmapper to a sink stream.

   /* Here is the code for flatmapper which is Step1 is above description*/

   public class NegativeBalanceMapper implements KeyValueMapper>>
   {
   private final BusinessRuleValidator businessRuleValidator;
   private final StoreHolder            storeHolder;

   ```
   public NegativeBalanceMapper(StoreHolder storeHolder, BusinessRuleValidator businessRuleValidator)
   {
       this.storeHolder = storeHolder;
       this.businessRuleValidator = businessRuleValidator;
   }

   public Iterable<KeyValue<String, BalanceEntry>> apply(String key, CommandEntry value)
   {
       List<KeyValue<String, BalanceEntry>> result = new ArrayList<>();
       if (value == null)
       {
           return result;
       }

       final ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, BalanceEntry> ledgerStore = storeHolder.getLedgerStore();
       if (ledgerStore != null)
       {
           KeyValueIterator<String, BalanceEntry> range = ledgerStore.all();
           while (range.hasNext())
           {
               KeyValue<String, BalanceEntry> next = range.next();
               if (businessRuleValidator.isNegativeBalance(next.value))
               {
                   result.add(new KeyValue<>(next.key, next.value));
               }
           }    
       }
       return result;
   }
   ```

   }

   /*Here is how it is invoked when a FLUSH command is received-step2 above*/
   final KStream negativeBalances = filteredCommandStream.flatMap(negativeBalanceMapper);

   /*Here i am pushing it out to a sink-step4 above*/

   negativeBalances.to(KafkaConstants.TOPIC_NEGATIVE_BALANCES,Produced.with(Serdes.String(), serdeRegistry.getBalanceEntrySerde()));

Thanks Matthias for the guidance.